# How to: can I test an application using both worker role AND VM role in Azure emulator?

Tags: testing, azure, emulation, virtual-machine, role

I've looked but can't see an answer to this one:
I have an application that passes Azure messages between a VM role and a worker role. Before I load this into Azure I'd like to test that both work correctly by using the Azure emulator.

Does anyone know if the Azure emulator will accept messages that originate from the VM role and will it allow me to send messages to the VM? Is there a workaround or solution to this?

Both the emulator and the VM will be running on the same host server in my case.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "passes Azure messages"? Are you referring to TCP/WCF? Azure Queues? Service Bus messages?

Comment: Sure David: My app. creates CloudQueueClients and uses CloudQueueMessages to pass operational information between VM and worker roles.

Comment: Sorry, I think I should have put the @David marker in that update...

Answer (score 0):

The queues are accessed as HTTP endpoints, so you need to ensure that both components you want to test can access the queue.

If you want to test your application using the storage emulator (an HTTP endpoint provisioned on your local machine, normally http://127.0.0.1:1001/) then you will to ensure that the VM role can get to that address.

I would recommend testing with the real storage service. There are difference between the emulator and the actual service, so it's better to test the real deal (you can always create a test queue).

In this case the endpoint will be on the internet (i.e. http://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/).

Comment: Great explanation.
Good advice about testing against a real storage account, thanks @Richard